# How to use the nested if function to parse to a string inside of a 'value if true' if statement?

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, nested

I am working on a title and description generator for online listings. I use an excel file and input variables like name, item type, authentication, notes, etc. Using these variables, I am developing a simple algorithm to generate a title and description for each item to list online to sites like eBay and Amazon. I would like to be able to generate an ideal title and description no matter what the case is. I have found myself in a weird spot for one case and don't know if it is possible to accomplish what I would like to do. I don't have the right wording for this case and forgive me for asking this simple question, but I would like to use a nested if statement during the 'value if true' part of an if statement. This nested if statement is going to add text to a string that is inside of the 'value if true.' Where I am currently at, my nested if statement returns 'FALSE.' I have rewritten this part of my algorithm to a very basic one and still receive 'FALSE.'

I have basic experience coding with JAVA, HTML, CSS, and I try to translate this experience to excel but I cannot figure out this issue. This issue might come from my inexperience with Excel's formatting. Here is a broken down version of the code that I would like to accomplish:

`=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(I2),ISTEXT(I2)),"This card was graded a "&I2&IF(OR(F2="P",F2="p")," by PSA. "," by JSA."))`

In this case, I would like the if statement to return: "This card was graded a *9* by *PSA.* assuming the two variables are I2=9 and F2=P. This code returns FALSE and I cannot figure it out. Once I figure out the correct way of accomplishing this, I will add many different cases for the two variables, I2 and F2. Thank you for helping me, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: you have nothing that to return if the cell is an error or empty.  so if the cell is either and error or empty it will return `FALSE`.  IF takes 3 arguments, `IF(criteria,TRUE,FALSE)` you only filled in the first two.

Comment: `=IF(I2<>"","This card was graded a "&I2&IF(F2="P"," by PSA. "," by JSA."),"")` If is not case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you to both of you for the help. I really appreciate it.